# Blank UITableView when Using Push Segue from UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a simple application which consists of a `UITabBarController` with 4 Tabs. On the first tab, I had a `UITableViewController` with a static list of languages (designed in `Interface Builder`). This `UITableViewController` is called `Videos`. I also have a `LanguagesFromVideos` `UITableViewController` which is also designed in `Interface Builder`. This is a dynamic `UITableView`.

If the user clicks on the first cell, they would be taken to the in the `Videos UITableView` `LanguagesFromVideos` and it will be populated with data for that language and if the user clicked on the second cell, it would be populated with data from that language. I had a segue per row on the `Videos` in `Interface Builder`.

I am changing the design so that the Videos tab will now be a `UICollectionViewController` instead of a `UITableViewController`.

I have designed that in `Interface Builder` with a single cell, where all `cells` are populated dynamically from within the code with the use of `NSArray`.

**Issue**

The issue I am facing now is that the segue doesn't occur properly from a cell in the `UICollectionView` to the `LanguagesFromVideo`. If I click on Chinese, it's supposed to show the Chinese information in the `LanguagesFromVideo UITableView` and if I click on English, it's supposed to show that in the `LanguagesFromVideo`, etc.

I am not seeing any desired results here. I click on Chinese and it loads a view, but the view is blank.

It's important for the segue to be push.

In my `UICollectionViewCell` `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, I have:

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    VideosTabCollectionCell *videosTabCell = (VideosTabCollectionCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if ([videosTabCell.videosTabCellLabel.text isEqualToString:@"Chinese\n汉语"])
    {
        LanguageFromVideoTabTableViewController *lfvtvc = [[LanguageFromVideoTabTableViewController alloc] init];
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Chinese Videos" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSArray *listOfVideos = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        NSMutableArray *availableVideosToPass = [listOfVideos mutableCopy];

        NSString *theSelectedLanguage = @"Chinese - 汉语";

//        [self presentViewController:lfvtvc animated:YES completion:nil];

        [lfvtvc setAvailableVideos:availableVideosToPass];
        [lfvtvc setSelectedLanguage:theSelectedLanguage];

    }

}
```

Previously, the `LanguagesFromVideo` `UITableView` was populated with the use of the text file, etc. Nothing is changing on that part. I still need to go from the Chinese `UICollectionViewCell` to the `LanguagesFromVideo`, showing the Chinese information and the same with other languages.

This isn't working and I'm quite stuck on this. I notice there's no `prepareForSegue` method on `UICollectionView`.

**Update**

I have created a `push segue` in `Interface Builder` from the `Videos UICollectionView` to the `LanguagesFromVideo UITableView` and called it: `languagesFromVideoSegue`. In the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`, I tried:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"languagesFromVideoSegue" sender:self];
```

That brought about a segue to a blank view controller. I'm guessing it hasn't loaded up the `LanguagesFromVideo` with the content that I'm providing in this `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`.

**Update 2**

With trying the use of the prepareForSegue instead of the didSelectItemAtIndexPath, I have:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"languagesFromVideoSegue"])
    {
        LanguageFromVideoTabTableViewController *lfvtvc = (LanguageFromVideoTabTableViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
        // Here, I will create the text file with a list of languages. The text file
        // already exists and we are passing it in here, with the creation of a NSArray
        // and then creating a copy for an NSMutableArray to pass.
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Chinese Videos" ofType:@"txt"];
        NSString *testString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:filePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
        NSArray *listOfVideos = [testString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
        NSMutableArray *availableVideosToPass = [listOfVideos mutableCopy];

        NSString *theSelectedLanguage = @"Chinese - 汉语";

        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"languagesFromVideoSegue" sender:@"Chinese"];
        //        [self presentViewController:lfvtvc animated:YES completion:nil];
        [segue destinationViewController];
        [lfvtvc setAvailableVideos:availableVideosToPass];
        [lfvtvc setSelectedLanguage:theSelectedLanguage];

    }

}
```

With this, the segue doesn't occur at all.

**Update 3**

I have set the `segue` in `Interface Builder` from the View Controller itself, not from the `UICollectionViewCell`. Now in the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` (without using the `prepareForSegue`), I am running the code seen above, but with the addition of :

```
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"languagesFromVideoSegue" sender:self];
```

The `segue` occurs, but it's blank, because the `self.selectedLanguages` is nil in the `LanguagesFromVideo` (it's not nil before being passed).

Any thoughts on this would be really appreciated.

Comment: UICollectionViewController has prepareForSegue, as it inherits from UIViewController. "Intercept" your segue in prepareForSegue and set your data there.

Comment: Hi Joern - thanks very much for the response and you are correct - I am working with that now, but it's not segueing and I can't understand why. I would segue depending on the cellTitle, but in prepareForSegue, this code doesn't work:     VideosTabCollectionCell *videosTabCell = (VideosTabCollectionCell *)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath]; as there isn't a collectionView parameter. I'm just confused as to how to achieve this. Please could I ask you to perhaps put in an answer with a sample code, if you're able to?

Comment: Use the sender parameter in performSegueWithIdentifier to get your data. If you start it inside call performSegueWithIdentifier inside didSelectRowAtIndexPath, your cell will be passed as sender.

Comment: Thanks Joern - how do I react to what the sender is sending in the LanguagesFromVideo? Also, would my setAvailableVideos and setSelectedLanguage still get called? That's the logic behind this entire UITableView. - just updated the question as well

Comment: Wuh, format your code :)

Comment: Ouch! My bad. That was painful to look at!

Comment: Okay....take a look at my solution. Maybe it gets a bit clearer. Start the segue within didSelectRowAtIndexPath or via Storyboard. Everything else may be something for a new question.

Comment: Thanks @JörnBuitink - it's *sort off* a bit clearer, but also I'm still a bit confused. Is there any chance we could discuss this in the chat if you're available for a few minutes?

Comment: Sorry - I do get the concept, but I can't make anything actually happen with it and that's the confusing part. Perhaps if you're around a bit later today - there's a few moving parts here and I'm not sure how to relate it to my code, etc. I appreciate your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
```

if you added your segue as push segue from your collection inside the storyboard. In this case, the selected cell will be the *sender*.
If you start the segue programatically in *didSelectRowAtIndexPath*, you can pass whatever your want as sender.

Than use prepareForSegue to set your data:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    [super prepareForSegue:segue sender:sender];

    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = sender;
        // now you can set your data.
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Joern - the only way I can get this partially working is to put the segue in the interface builder and in the didSelectItemAtIndexPath, I put         [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"languagesFromVideoSegue" sender:self]; - the segue does happen but it's entirely blank. Referencing the question - the setSelectedLanguage gets called before the viewWillAppear, but within that, self.selectedLanguages is nil. I don't understand what's going on with this and your thoughts are really appreciated.

Comment: I managed to get it working with your guidance - thanks very much! I appreciate it!